# How can I specify another server to copy the build files onto?

Tags: msbuild, teamcity

I'm trying to create a MSBuild script for running in TeamCity. I have a problem when I want to copy the files generated by the Project Build to another server. I tried to map that server as X:\ but I got the error that it can't find that path. Can anybody help me?
Thanks

Comment: are you mapping that drive for the login that the team city service is using?

Comment: I've mapped that drive from MyComputer and checked Connect at Logon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drive mappings can be problematic to use from build scripts. It would be better if you can use a network share. If not you may have to use a tool like [MSDeploy](http://www.iis.net/download/WebDeploy).

Comment: I think he meant using an UNC path to the shared network resource.

Answer (score 0):

Like David commented above, you need to run the Teamcity Agent service as the user that has the drive mapped. To do that, go to the Services console, right click the service "Teamcity Build Agent", Properties, Log On, This account.

What I usually do is to use UNC path and if needed, before reaching the path I authenticate with "net use \machine\folder /USER:domain\user password".