# In TeamCity, what is the preferred way to copy and delete an app_offline.htm file during the build?

Tags: asp.net, msbuild, teamcity

I am a TeamCity and continuous integration newbie, and I'm trying to figure out how to copy an [app_offline.htm](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/10/06/426755.aspx) file into a folder on the destination web server at the start of each build.

My "approach 0" was to try a Command Line runner with the following script:

```
copy Some\Path\app_offline.htm %system.Target.IIS.PublishPath%
```

Where `%system.Target.IIS.PublishPath%` is a user-defined parameter that contains the URI for the target web site root folder.  For example, `\\someserver\C$\inetpub\...`.

When I run this step, the log shows a failure with the following message:

```
Step 1/8: Stop ASP.NET site and redirect users to offline status page (Command Line)
[15:53:47][Step 1/8] Starting: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\agentTmp\custom_script12345.cmd
[15:53:47][Step 1/8] in directory: C:\TeamCity\Project\Checkout\Path\src
[15:53:47][Step 1/8] The user name or password is incorrect.
[15:53:47][Step 1/8]         0 file(s) copied.
[15:53:47][Step 1/8] Process exited with code 1
[15:53:47][Step 1/8] Step Stop ASP.NET site and redirect users to offline status page (Command Line) failed
```

As a test, I logged in to one of my VMs using the TeamCity AD account, and I was able to successfully run the script when I run it from a command prompt that has administrative privileges.

After some googling, I found [this approach](http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2010/09/28/continuous-integration-tip-2-ndash-using-appofflinehtm-in-your-build), but this seems to run within the scope of the MSBuild, and seems better-suited for situations where the web site is being deployed locally.

Is there a better approach?  I'm a bit too green to have a sense of what steps "belong" as isolated TeamCity build steps, vs. pre-build and post-build tasks for MSBuild.

Comment: This TeamCity AD account - is that the account running the actual TeamCity service (Build Agent service) or is it just the account TC uses to pull code/do other stuff? Remember that the user that is actually running the service needs to have the correct permissions. You can look that up under Services in Windows.

Comment: The AD account is the one that runs the actual TeamCity service.  I've confirmed that it has administrative permissions on the target web server.

Comment: It looks like the step works when I start the step with a call to `net use`, per [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645209/how-can-i-specify-another-server-to-copy-the-build-files-onto)...